# SQL Server Query is invalid

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having the following error with this query in SQL server 2014 "Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator."

```
SUM (DISTINCT (studentsip.AdminNO)) AS NoOfStudentsAllocated
```

Comment: Looks pretty clear? You are trying to get the sum of a column of strings...

Comment: COUNT instead of SUM?

Comment: what are u trying to do? check the data type of AdminNO @Weeliang Koh

Comment: Show sample data please.

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result. (As well formatted text.)

Comment: Unrelated, but: `distinct` is ***NOT*** a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count the number of students (as suggested by the column name), then use `COUNT()`, not `SUM()`:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT studentsip.AdminNO) AS NoOfStudentsAllocated
```

I have a certain amount of experience with SQL.  I have never used `SUM(DISTINCT)`.  I wish the language did not allow the syntax.

I should note that if the `DISTINCT` is not needed, then you should not use it.  `DISTINCT` almost always slows down queries.

Answer (score 1):

Your field is of type `varchar`.  To use it in `sum()` you need to `convert()` it to `int`:

```
sum(distinct(convert(int,studentsip.AdminNO))) as NoOfStudentsAllocated
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the number of students that have each value of AdminNo, you can use **count** and **group by**:

```
select AdminNO, count(1) as NoOfStudentsAllocated 
from studentsip 
group by AdminNO 
order by AdminNO
```